# How to use Constructors/Casting with Generic Types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, constructor, casting

I have a parent class, `Parent`, with two child classes, `A` and `B`. I have another class, `Wrapper<Type1,Type2>`, that contains an interface, `Function<Type1,Type2>`, which is supposed to transform an A into a B or a B into an A.

If I define

```
new Wrapper<A,B>(new Function<A,B>(){public B transform(A a){return new B(a);}});
```

outside of the `Wrapper` class, then this works fine.

I run into the problem that I can't instantiate a generic type when I want to define a default `Function` for the default constructor `public Wrapper()` within the `Wrapper<Type1,Type2>` class itself.

Eclipse recommends casting from `Type1` to `Type2`, but the problem is that A can't cast to B because they are sibling classes. I do have constructors for `Parent(Parent)`, `A(B)`, and `B(A)`, so it would be great if I could implement a generic constructor somehow. How can I work around this?

```
public class Parent {
    protected int value = 0;
    public void setValue(int x){ value = x; }
    public int getValue(){ return value; }
    public Parent(){}
    public Parent(A a){setValue(a.getValue());}
    public Parent(B b){setValue(b.getValue());}
    public Parent(Parent p){setValue(p.getValue());}
}


public class A extends Parent{
    public A(){ setValue(1); }
    public A(B b){ setValue( b.getValue()); }
}

public class B extends Parent{
    public B(){ setValue(2); }
    public B(A a){ setValue(a.getValue()); }
}


public interface Function <Type1 extends Parent, Type2 extends Parent> {
    public Type2 transform(Type1 t);
}


public class Wrapper<Type1 extends Parent, Type2 extends Parent> {

    Function<Type1,Type2> function;
    public Wrapper(Function<Type1,Type2> x){ function = x; }
    public Wrapper(){
        function = new Function<Type1,Type2>(){
            public Type2 transform(Type1 t){
            ///I want to use constructor Type2(t), given that they both extend Parent
                //return new Type2( t);
                return (Type2) t; ///causes an error because can't cast from A to B
            }

        };
    }
    public Type2 transform(Type1 t){
        return function.transform(t);
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ///Start with custom function. This part works.
        Wrapper<A,B> wrapper = new Wrapper<A,B>(
            new Function<A,B>(){
                public B transform(A a){
                    ///Want to use constructor B(a)
                    ///Can't cast A to B
                    return new B(a);
                }
            }
        );
        A a = new A();
        B b = wrapper.transform(a);

        ///This part works
        System.out.println(b.getValue());

        ///Next try the default Function
        wrapper = new Wrapper<A,B>();
        b = wrapper.transform(a); ///This part causes the error, as wrapper attempts to cast from A to B
        System.out.println(b.getValue());


    }
}
```

***Edit:***

My question is unique in scope and implementation from the suggested duplicate. E.g., the structure of my code is a simple parent with two sibling child classes. The structure in the possible duplicate is more intricate, involving multiple generations and child classes that are disheveled in a confusing way. I'm not sure what that code is attempting to do, and the answer didn't help me understand my own question in the slightest as it seemed particular to the distinct structure of the other question.

Comment: I think that your function is doing too much, and following SRP It should do one thing, or transform from A to B or from B to A, you cannot use different functions?

Comment: @vmrvictor I could potentially create different functions, however, in the actual code I have many child classes. 5 child classes would require 5^5 functions, (the function must reflexively take A->A as well). The actual code does more than transform. This was just a simple version to illustrate the question.

Comment: @vmrvictor I appreciate your suggestion of a duplicate question, however, I frankly don't understand that question or that answer. I believe my question is sufficiently distinct from that one based on their scope and implementation. E.g., the structure in mine is a simple parent with two sibling children, whereas the structure in the possible duplicate has a parent with two generations and many more child classes disheveled in a confusing way. Visiting that link hasn't helped me understand my question in the slightest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to make a "generic" constructor. The solution closes to your current implementation is to instantiate objects in your `function`. As this is anyway the responsibility of the caller (in your design), then it's easy:

```
Wrapper<A, B> wrapper = new Wrapper<A, B>((a) -> new B(a));
```

But where the default `Wrapper()` constructor is being called, you can make the caller send `Class` objects for type1 and type2:

```
public Wrapper(Class<Type1> type1Class, Class<Type2> type2Class) {
    this.function = (object1) -> {
        try {
            return type2Class.getConstructor(type1Class).newInstance(object1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

With both of the above, your main method will look like the following:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Wrapper<A, B> wrapper = new Wrapper<A, B>((a) -> new B(a));

    A a = new A();
    B b = wrapper.transform(a);

    System.out.println(b.getValue());

    wrapper = new Wrapper<A, B>(A.class, B.class);
    b = wrapper.transform(a);
    System.out.println(b.getValue());
}
```

And this runs without any type cast errors.

---

The java1.7 version of the above lambda expressions:

```
Wrapper<A, B> wrapper = new Wrapper<A, B>(new Function<A, B>() {
    @Override
    public B transform(A a) {
        return new B(a);
    }
});
```

And:

```
this.function = new Function<Type1, Type2>() {

    @Override
    public Type2 transform(Type1 object1) {
        try {
            return type2Class.getConstructor(type1Class).newInstance(object1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting an error under `object1`. Eclipse is telling me to create a local variable for object1. I'm using Eclipse 3.8 on an old mac, so maybe this is something my old version doesn't know. I'm unfamiliar with the `()->{}` notation. Could you explain it to me? I read something about lambda function just now, but in short it looks like it's shorthand for implementing the interface.

Comment: @user2303321 I assumed you're using java 8 or later as you're using the `Function` interface. Is your eclipse set up to compile with 1.8 as target? Won't work if target version is older. You're right about lambdas. You can also check this https://dzone.com/articles/lambda-expression-in-java8

Comment: Unfortunately, Eclipse 3.8 only supports up to Java 1.7. Is it just the lambda function notation that is not supported or is the instantiation of objects not supported either? Could I implement this same idea with standard interface notation?

Comment: @user2303321 Which package is `Function` from? And yes, you can onvert those lambda expressions to anonymous classes.

Comment: They are all in the same package. Function is just my own defined class. Would this be the correct implementation? 
`public Wrapper(final Class<Type1> type1Class, final Class<Type2> type2Class) {
     this.function = new Function<Type1,Type2>(){
      public Type2 transform(Type1 object1){
       try {
        return type2Class.getConstructor(type1Class).newInstance(object1);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
      };
     };
 }`

Comment: @user2303321 That looks right. I've edited the answer to add java7 versions of those lambdas

Comment: Great! You've been a big help. One final question: how do I  instantiate the default constructor from main? I'm trying something like `wrapper = new Wrapper<A,B>(Class<A>,Class<B>);` but I simply don't know how to implement this, or what this procedure is called.

Comment: @user2303321 It's in the third code block of this answer (`wrapper = new Wrapper<A, B>(A.class, B.class);`)

Comment: Oops. Missed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not possible to create an instance using a generic type parameter we must work around it. I'll restrict the answer to Java 7 as I read from the comments you're working with.  Here is my suggestion:

```
public interface Transform<P extends Parent> {

    P with(int value);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Transform<B> transformToB = new Transform<B>() {

        @Override
        public B with(int value) {
            return new B(value);
        }

    };

    A a = new A();
    B b = transformToB.with(a.getValue());
    System.out.println(b.getValue());
}
```

How it works?
We have an interface `Transform<P extends Parent>` defining the method `with`. This method has one parameter. This is the only one field of the classes you defined. Using this value the method has to return an instance of some `P` which extends `Parent`. Looking at the implementation of `transformToB` it creates a `B` instance by calling the (by me added) constructor `B(int value)`.

Why another constructor?
Declaring constructors like `B(A a)` or `A(B b)` results in a circular dependency between these classes. `A` and `B` aren't [loosely coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). Declaring a constructor which takes only a `value` we instantiate the state without having to know where this `value` comes from.

Also declaring constructors like `Parent(A a)` and  `Parent(B b)` introduces dependencies to `Parent` on it's subclasses. Following this approach `Parent`  would need to provide a constructor for each subclass.

Possible extension:
If `value` is just an example for many other fields, we do not want to define a constructor like `A(int value1, int value2, String value3, ...)` having many parameters. Instead of we could use the default constructor `A()` and do the transformation like this:

```
interface Transform<From extends Parent, To extends Parent> {

    To from(From f);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Transform<A, B> transformToB = new Transform<A, B>() {

        @Override
        public B from(A a) {
            B b = new B();
            b.setValue(a.getValue());
            b.setValue2(a.getValue2());
            b.setValue3(a.getValue3());

            return b;
        }

    };

    A a = new A();
    B b = transformToB.from(a);

    System.out.println(b.getValue());
}
```

This last approach is also applicable if `A` and `B` have different fields. In case `B` has a field `String value4` we could add an additional line to `transformToB` like                 `b.setValue4(a.getValue3()+"#"+a.getValue2());`.